# C# documentation examples

Tags: c#, msdn

I am a newbie in comp. programming and have difficulty understanding the examples in the C# documentation. For example, the beginning of [the Arrays as Objects section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z4khca9.aspx) in the MSDN programming guide goes like this.

*You can use the properties, and other class members, that Array has. The following code assigns the length of the `numbers` array, which is 5, to a variable called `lengthOfNumbers`:*

C#

```
using System;
using System.Text;
```

Now, I don't see any `numbers` array and no variable called `lengthOfNumbers`. Please help my code-resistant brain get this.
Thank you!

Comment: It is simply a borked MSDN entry.

Comment: Nor do I , the docs are broken in that page.

Comment: Broken MSDN example. Check it's 2013 version. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z4khca9%28v=vs.120%29.aspx You can send them this situation as a feedback.

Comment: On the 'Other versions' link at the top, go to something other than VS 2015 and it displays fine.

Comment: Thanks. I was starting to think that I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a borked MSDN example. Nothing to worry about.

[The Visual Studio 2013 version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z4khca9(v=vs.120).aspx) does show the expected code:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int lengthOfNumbers = numbers.Length;
```